# How can I read SQL Server filestream with ASP.NET Core

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, sqlfilestream

I'm looking for a way to convert `Pic.PathName()` and           `GET_FILESTREAM_TRANSACTION_CONTEXT()` to provide a link for downloading in ASP.NET Core.

I have seen `SqlFileStream` in .NET Framework, but it does not work in .NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a reasonable way to get file handle access to filestream blobs from .NET core.  Techincally on Windows you could get the file handle through P/Invoke and the ODBC driver, but you probably would never want to do that.

Because you can very easily get streaming access to the filestream blob through SQL Server.  There's a slight performance advantage to using the handle-based access, but probably not enough to matter.  If you really need that, you're probably better off using [FileTables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017), and just accessing the file using a UNC path.

Anyway, filestream blobs are accessable as varbinary(max) columns on the table, and .NET SqlClient supports streaming blobs.  See [SqlClient Streaming Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sqlclient-streaming-support) for info and examples.  If it's a large file you'll want to stream the result directly to the client.

Comment: @david-browne-microsoft I have a question: what is `handle-based access`? can you describe more?!

Comment: @amir133 see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filestream-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017